# How to implement animated header with flatlist in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I would need an animation as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/1vt3uCq_Y1g?si=9Z0RaJRRqrMt5ICn

The general animation is as such: When you start to scroll the list, the header collapses with nice smooth animation from current height to fixed min height based on scrolling list’s scroll value and sticks on the top of the screen

However, this implementation shown in the video is with scroll view but i need it to render my items in a flatlist. How can i change the animations? I am working on android platform only

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please check out [ask] when you can - you're encouraged to code your own best effort, and ask here with specific errors or questions.  "I need an animation" sounds like you want someone to write the code for you (not allowed), and elicits opinion-based answers (also not allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really similar like ScrollViews, here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@michael.bahl/interactiveheader-with-flatlist)

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import FeatherIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const items = [
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518684079-3c830dcef090?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80',
    name: 'Dubai',
    airport: 'DXB',
    departure: '2022-10-10',
    arrival: '2023-04-01',
    price: 966,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516483638261-f4dbaf036963?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=986&q=80',
    name: 'Italy',
    airport: 'VCE',
    departure: '2022-10-10',
    arrival: '2023-04-01',
    price: 652,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623536167776-922ccb1ff749?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=544&q=80',
    name: 'Bosnia',
    airport: 'BNX',
    departure: '2022-10-10',
    arrival: '2023-04-01',
    price: 566,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554939437-ecc492c67b78?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80',
    name: 'Spain',
    airport: 'BCN',
    departure: '2022-10-10',
    arrival: '2023-04-01',
    price: 602,
  },
];

export default function Example() {
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const translateHeader = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 80],
    outputRange: [0, -80],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  const opacityTitle = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  const translateTitle = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 80],
    outputRange: [0, 40],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#05141c' }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.header,
          { transform: [{ translateY: translateHeader }] },
        ]}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={[
            styles.headerTitle,
            { opacity: opacityTitle },
            ,
            { transform: [{ translateY: translateTitle }] },
          ]}>
          Cheap flights{'\n'}to anywhere
        </Animated.Text>

        <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Where are you going?"
            placeholderTextColor="#05141c"
            style={styles.input}
          />

          <View style={styles.inputIcon}>
            <FeatherIcon color="#05141c" name="search" size={16} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
      <Animated.FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }
        )}
        data={items}
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        renderItem={(
          { item: { img, name, airport, departure, arrival, price } },
          index
        ) => {
          return (
            <View key={index} style={{ opacity: 0.25 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  // handle onPress
                }}>
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <Image
                    alt=""
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    source={{ uri: img }}
                    style={styles.cardImg}
                  />

                  <View style={styles.cardBody}>
                    <Text>
                      <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{name}</Text>{' '}
                      <Text style={styles.cardAirport}>{airport}</Text>
                    </Text>

                    <View style={styles.cardRow}>
                      <View style={styles.cardRowItem}>
                        <FontAwesome
                          color="#6f61c4"
                          name="plane-departure"
                          size={10}
                        />

                        <Text style={styles.cardRowItemText}>
                          {new Date(departure).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
                            day: 'numeric',
                            month: 'short',
                            year: 'numeric',
                          })}
                        </Text>
                      </View>

                      <View style={styles.cardRowItem}>
                        <FontAwesome
                          color="#6f61c4"
                          name="plane-arrival"
                          size={10}
                        />

                        <Text style={styles.cardRowItemText}>
                          {new Date(arrival).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
                            day: 'numeric',
                            month: 'short',
                            year: 'numeric',
                          })}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>

                    <Text style={styles.cardPrice}>
                      <Text>from </Text>

                      <Text style={styles.cardPriceValue}>
                        ${price?.toLocaleString('en-US')}{' '}
                      </Text>

                      <Text style={styles.cardPriceCurrency}>USD</Text>
                    </Text>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
                        // handle onPress
                      }}>
                      <View style={styles.btn}>
                        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Book now</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  content: {
    padding: 24,
    paddingTop: 212,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    zIndex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    height: 200,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: '#05141c',
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 26,
    lineHeight: 34,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  input: {
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingLeft: 44,
    paddingRight: 24,
    borderRadius: 12,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#222',
  },
  inputWrapper: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '100%',
  },
  inputIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 44,
    height: 44,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    borderRadius: 12,
    marginBottom: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  cardImg: {
    width: 120,
    height: 154,
    borderRadius: 12,
  },
  cardBody: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexShrink: 1,
    flexBasis: 0,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
  },
  cardTitle: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#173153',
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  cardAirport: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#5f697d',
  },
  cardRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: -8,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  cardRowItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 6,
  },
  cardRowItemText: {
    marginLeft: 4,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#5f697d',
  },
  cardPrice: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#5f697d',
  },
  cardPriceValue: {
    fontSize: 21,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#173153',
  },
  cardPriceCurrency: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#6f61c4',
  },
  btn: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    paddingHorizontal: 14,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#173153',
    borderColor: '#173153',
  },
  btnText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    lineHeight: 18,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```